# Ethernet communications bypass Relay specs question

Tags: relay, ethernet, telecommunications, bypass

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:** Added another diagram to help understand that if a daisy chained device looses power, that the signal relay with power would use the normally open contacts with the device still being able to communicate normally. When power is lost, the Relay contacts go to there default un-powered state, normally closed, and bypass the device that lost power, so other devices can still function and communicate on the network without being blocked.

**Want to use a Relay to bypass Ethernet communications with a dual Ethernet port device**

I'm creating a dual ethernet device with dual ethernet jacks for daisy chaining. I've researched and seen how others either use STP or RSTP if a device loses power to keep communications going with a daisy chain of devices.

I have a device that currently uses the Microchip ENC28J60 microcontroller and works perfect.

I want to add another ethernet port for dual ports and researched and found the most simple way is to use a Relay powered on with normally closed connections being open with power as shown in picture.

When power is lost, the relay loses power, and the contacts close keeping ethernet communication going.

I've searched and have not found a "**Ethernet Bypass Relay**" and only generic relays keep showing up.

I'm looking for relay specs that would be required to keep 10/100mbs going in case of power loss of device.

I need it to be a small micro relay so as not to consume PCB board space.

What would the electrical specs for having ethernet signals pass thru the relay be ?

**Or are there relays specifically made already for this application**, and if so, can anyone provide some part numbers and or manufactures or feedback or direction on what terms to look for for searching to weed out generic relays so signal integrity is kept intact ? I can't filter google feedback enough to be specific on my search.

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: That diagram will not work. When relay loses power, it will simply short out RX pair to TX pair on a single Ethernet connection, which kind of makes no sense. First of all that would be the same as creating a loopback plug for the Ethernet switch so it sees itself as a link partner. And it may not even work, as both the TX and RX pair would be differentially terminated into 100 ohms, so the switch TX would see three 100 ohm terminations instead of one. And, a relay that can pass the Ethernet traffic in such fidelity that it still is within Ethernet specifications would be extremely expensive.

Comment: This will be interesting, your switch will think there is another device with the same IP, that is not allowed.  Why not just use two separate independent ethernet connections. and do the switch in software if one fails.  You could also bridge them if you like.  As far as a relay I know of none, the number of twists etc required in the PHY causes problems as would an unterminated pair.

Comment: Added another diagram to help understand that if a daisy chained device looses power, that signal relay with power would use the normally open contacts and with the device to still be able to communicate. When power is lost, the Relay contacts go to there default un-powered state, and bypass the device that lost power, so other devices and still function and communicate on the network.

Comment: EDIT: Added another diagram to help understand that if a daisy chained device looses power, that the signal relay with power would use the normally open contacts with the device still being able to communicate normally. When power is lost, the Relay contacts go to there default un-powered state, normally closed, and bypass the device that lost power, so other devices can still function and communicate on the network without being blocked.